# How to reload fragment or refresh fragment on TabReselected Using ActionBar Tabs

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**DESCRIPTION**::

1. There is a `ActionBarTab(3-tab)` setup, We are linking three fragments
   for each Action-Tab, Each fragment contains a `listview`
2. Whenever we are clicking Tab, we are sorting data.
3. In `onTabReselect` i am calling sort function using interface method,
   without error it executes but its not refreshing the `listview`

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Toast.makeText(this, DosUtils.ExecuteDOSCommand(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        // Initialize
        FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.initFindMyBuffetApplicationCls(MainActivity.this);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        appContext = getApplicationContext();

        //ActionBar
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab RatingTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(FindMyBuffetConstants.TAB_NAME_RATING);
        ActionBar.Tab PriceTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(FindMyBuffetConstants.SORT_BY_PRICE);
        ActionBar.Tab DistanceTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(FindMyBuffetConstants.SORT_BY_DISTANCE);

        Fragment SortRestFragmentByRating = new SortRestaurantRating();
        Fragment SortRestFragmentByPrice = new SortRestaurantByPrice();
        Fragment SortRestFragmentByDistance = new SortRestaurantByDistance();

        RatingTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(SortRestFragmentByRating));
        PriceTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(SortRestFragmentByPrice));
        DistanceTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(SortRestFragmentByDistance));

        actionbar.addTab(RatingTab);
        actionbar.addTab(PriceTab);
        actionbar.addTab(DistanceTab);

        FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.comm = (Communicator) new SortRestaurantByPrice();
    }
class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(tab.getText().toString()==FindMyBuffetConstants.TAB_NAME_RATING){
            if(FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isRatingOrderByDesc==false){
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isRatingOrderByDesc=true;
            }
            else {
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isRatingOrderByDesc=false;
            }

        }

        if(tab.getText().toString()==FindMyBuffetConstants.SORT_BY_PRICE){
            if(FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isPriceOrderByDesc==false){
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isPriceOrderByDesc=true;
            }
            else {
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isPriceOrderByDesc=false;
            }

            FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.comm.RefreshFragment();
        }

        if(tab.getText().toString()==FindMyBuffetConstants.SORT_BY_DISTANCE){
            if(FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isDistanceOrderByDesc==false){
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isDistanceOrderByDesc=true;
            }
            else {
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isDistanceOrderByDesc=false;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        ft.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
        if(tab.getText().toString()==FindMyBuffetConstants.TAB_NAME_RATING){
            if(FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isRatingOrderByDesc==false)
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isRatingOrderByDesc=true;
            else 
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isRatingOrderByDesc=false;
        }

        if(tab.getText().toString()==FindMyBuffetConstants.SORT_BY_PRICE){
            if(FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isPriceOrderByDesc==false)
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isPriceOrderByDesc=true;
            else 
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isPriceOrderByDesc=false;
        }

        if(tab.getText().toString()==FindMyBuffetConstants.SORT_BY_DISTANCE){
            if(FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isDistanceOrderByDesc==false)
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isDistanceOrderByDesc=true;
            else 
                FindMyBuffetApplicationCls.isDistanceOrderByDesc=false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
        Log.i("TEST TAB",tab.getText().toString());

    }

}
```

**SortRestaurantByPrice.java**

```
public class SortRestaurantByPrice extends Fragment implements Communicator{
    // Declaration
    ListView xmlFragmentListView;
    SortRestaurantListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    View layout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_restaurant_by_price, container,false);
        xmlFragmentListView = ((ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.sortrestaurantbypricelistview));
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        //layout = null; // now cleaning up!
    }

    private void SortRestaurantList(String strSortBy)
            throws Exception, TransformerConfigurationException,
            TransformerException, FindMyBuffetException {

        // Process the Main Screen Data
        List<RestaurantDetails> lstRest = null;     
                    lstRest = SAXXMLParser.parse(xmlInputStream);
                    SortRestaurantListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new SortRestaurantListViewAdapter(lstRest);
                    xmlFragmentListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void RefreshFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("hELLO", "refresh requested. Try to reload data for this fragment...");
            SortRestaurantList("Price");

    }
}
```

**Communicator.java**

```
public interface Communicator {
    public void RefreshFragment();
}
```

Comment: Please call `notifyDataSetChanges()` on your List Adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Please call notifyDataChanged method on your list in the sortRestaurantList method.

```
 private void SortRestaurantList(String strSortBy)
        throws Exception, TransformerConfigurationException,
        TransformerException, FindMyBuffetException {

    // Process the Main Screen Data
    List<RestaurantDetails> lstRest = null;     
                lstRest = SAXXMLParser.parse(xmlInputStream);
                SortRestaurantListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new SortRestaurantListViewAdapter(lstRest);
                xmlFragmentListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
       listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // call this on Adapter

}
```

Infact move the adapter code in the onCreateView method. Only modify (sort) your List lstRest in the SortRestaurant method and after that call the notifyDataSetChanged method.

Comment: It is giving this error:: ...... The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListView ...... (&) it is providing two suggestion Change to deferNotifyDatasetChanged .... and ... add cast to method reciever ...... listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ...or ..... xmlFragmentListView.defernotifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, call this method on the list adapter of yours instead. I have edited my answer. :)